# How to Redirect from old format to new format

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to configure my htaccess file to handle our new url format. I KNOW that the htaccess file is working. I am trying to tweak what is NOT working.

I have about 1200 links that look like this...

```
http://www.flyingpiston.com/bike/1014/
http://www.flyingpiston.com/bike/1015/
http://www.flyingpiston.com/bike/1016/
http://www.flyingpiston.com/bike/1017/
```

The new links look like this...

```
http://www.flyingpiston.com/bikes.cfm?id=1014
http://www.flyingpiston.com/bikes.cfm?id=1015
http://www.flyingpiston.com/bikes.cfm?id=1016
http://www.flyingpiston.com/bikes.cfm?id=1014
```

Here's the rule that I set up...

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^bike/([0-9]+)/ /bikes.cfm?id=$1 [NS,L]
```

Is there something obviously wrong with the rule? How can I write a rule that will enable me to redirect the old style links to the new style links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RedirectMatch` directive doesn't take any flags, so the `[]` bit needs to go away:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^bike/([0-9]+)/ /bikes.cfm?id=$1
```

But everthing else looks fine for redirecting when someone types:

```
http://example.com/bike/1234/
```

in the browser's address bar and change it (redirect) to:

```
http://example.com/bikes.cfm?id=1234
```

This is also assuming you're using apache and the directive is in an htaccess file in your document root.

Comment: Okay, but I have 1200+ distinct bike ids. Isn't there any regular expression that I can write that will enable me to not have to hard code all of those ids?

Comment: @EvikJames this does, the `([0-9]+)` captures **any** set of numbers and backreferences using `$1`. The 1234 is just an example.

Comment: I misunderstood you. I thought you meant the [0-9] not the [NS,L].